# for loop takes only last entry value (python/tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

EDIT: I've edited the code so it is runnable and all variables are defined.

I have this bit of code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class question_list:
    list = []

class question:
    answers = []
    def __init__(self,content):
        self.content = content

class Emotion:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        Emotion.name = name
        Emotion.value = value

class answer:
    emotions = [Emotion("Anger",0)]
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content




questions = question_list()
buttonlist = []
entries = []
clicked = 0

questions.list.append(question("On a scale of 1-10, is it moral?"))
for num in range(10):
    questions.list[0].answers.append(answer(num+1))

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(anchor = 'w')
Label1=Label(frame1, text = "You chose SCALE. Examine the scale below. Click each number to view a description and set the values for each given emotion.")
Label1.pack(anchor = 'w')

frame2 = Frame(frame1)
frame2.pack()
for num in range(1,11):
    btn = Button(frame2, text=num, command = lambda num=num:scaleset(num))
    btn.pack(side=LEFT)
    buttonlist.append(btn)


def scaleset(n):
    global clicked
    buttonlist[n - 1].config(state=DISABLED)
    clicked += 1
    frame3 = Frame(frame2)
    frame3.pack(anchor='w')
    label2 = Label(frame3, text="Enter a value between -10 and 10 for each emotion. Enter \"0\" for no effect.",
                           wraplength=700, justify=LEFT)
    label2.pack(anchor='w')
    button = Button(frame3, text="Continue", command=lambda: reset())
    for number in range(len((questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions))):
        frame = Frame(frame3)
        frame.pack(anchor='w')
        label = Label(frame, text=questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions[number].name)
        label.pack(side=LEFT)
        entry = Entry(frame)
        entry.pack(side=RIGHT)
        entries.append(entry)
    frame4 = Frame(frame3)
    frame4.pack(anchor='w')
    button2 = Button(frame4, text="Done", command=lambda:set_scaleanswers(frame4))
    button2.pack(side=LEFT)

    def set_scaleanswers(frame):
        for num in range(len(questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions)):
            questions.list[0].answers[clicked - 1].emotions[num].value = entries[num].get()
            HeaderScale2 = Label(frame, text="Answer recorded.")
            HeaderScale2.pack(side=RIGHT)
            button.pack(anchor='w')
            del entries[:]

        button2.config(state=DISABLED)

    def reset():
        frame3.destroy()




root.mainloop()
```

Say for the `1` button, the user inputs "1". For the `2` button, the user inputs "2". For the `3` button, the user inputs "3".

My expected results are:

`questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions[0].value = 1`
`questions.list[0].answers[1].emotions[0].value = 2`
`questions.list[0].answers[2].emotions[0].value = 3`

Instead I get:

`questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions[0].value = 3`
`questions.list[0].answers[1].emotions[0].value = 3`
`questions.list[0].answers[2].emotions[0].value = 3`

How do I fix it so I get my desired result?

Comment: Could you please set up a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to show us the definition of `questions`.

Comment: Added definition of questions @BoarGules

Comment: Please post a MCVE - your code snippet is not runnable and has qui a few undefined names.

Comment: Aren't those `answers` and `emotions` lists sort of "static" (in Java terms), shared for all the instances of the class?

Comment: @Feodoran I have added an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

The `Emotion` instance in all your `answer` class instances is the very same object. Thus if you change it for one `answer` instance, it is changed for all answers.

You can check this, by comparing their addresses in memory. Same address means same object. (You will have a different address there, but it is the same of all instances.)

```
>>> questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions
[<__main__.Emotion instance at 0x7fdad37c7290>]
>>> questions.list[0].answers[1].emotions
[<__main__.Emotion instance at 0x7fdad37c7290>]
```

You need to change its definition, so it becomes instance specific:

```
class answer:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.emotions = [Emotion("Anger",0)]
        self.content = content
```

Now the addresses will be different for each instance:

```
>>> questions.list[0].answers[0].emotions
[<__main__.Emotion instance at 0x7f4e4ce1ba28>]
>>> questions.list[0].answers[1].emotions
[<__main__.Emotion instance at 0x7f4e4b3575f0>]
```